# Make IntelliJ generate tests without throws Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

When I use the **Create Test** feature of IntelliJ IDEA, it generates test cases with a `throws Exception` clause, for example:

> ```
> @Test
> public void testIsInteger() throws Exception {
>
> }
> ```

This annoys me a bit: I prefer to add the specific `throws` clauses myself only when necessary.
That way I see at a glance what kind of exceptions might be thrown by each test case.

How can I change this behavior of IntelliJ to omit the `throws` clause?

Or am I wrong to want this? The creators seem to think this default behavior is a good thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go into *Settings/File and Code Templates/Code tab* and change the template for the JUnit test method (there are templates both for JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 test methods).

That should do the trick.

Comment: This answers how to make IDEA not generate the `throws Exception` clause, but not why this is good or bad practice. I wonder this too. I'd argue the same as @janos : I'd only want to see the clause if it is up to the method's caller to handle an `Exception` that is thrown somewhere in the methods code. However, when an `Exception` is thrown nowhere, then I do not want to specify this by default. Why does IDEA do this then? What are reasons to want this? By the way: the result is identical (test with a test method that immediately throws an exception).